# Import custom components in react from node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, babeljs

I am trying to develop a react component that could be shared across different applications. The idea is any app could drop in the component, pass in some props, and get the same functionality everywhere. So apps can add my component as a dependency in package.json which will be downloaded in node_modules. Basically go from doing this

`import testComponent from "./Components";`

to this

`import testComponent from "my-custom-components";`

I tried doing `npm install [githun-url-link]` which seemingly worked fine. But after launching the app I get the error:

```
Failed to Compile
./node_modules/.../src/components/testComponent.js
SyntaxError: /Users/mzq/Workspace/.../testing/node_modules/.../src/components/testComponent.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (7:9):

   5 | 
   6 | class testComponent extends Component {
>  7 |   state = {
     |         ^
   8 |     currentPageIndex: 0,
   9 |     currentPageLabel: this.props.currentPageLabel,
  10 |     page: this.props.pages[0],

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

One solution I tried after a bit of Googling is

1) `yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --dev`

2) creating a `babel.config.js` in the root folder with following config

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@babel/preset-typescript'
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
    ]
};
```

To no avail.

Comment: Have you added a build step so that your code is transpiled with babel before its published and used by other apps?